# Show Login-Screen on top, not within ion-nav-view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

my Ionic app has an abstract view ("main") with lots of sub-views, that are displayed in "ion-nav-view" (Side Menu). In my abstract main controller, I load a class (singleton) into the Scope (let's say it's named "test"). In my MainCtrl, I check if "test.user != 0" (i.e. if user is logged in). If false, I'd like to display a login screen ("welcome"), without showing the side-menu.

How can I achieve this?
When I define $stateProvider.state("welcome") without the abstract state "main", I cannot access "test" via Scope (test has a method for logging in via HTTP). So "welcome" has to be within main ($stateProvider.state("main.welcome")). But

```
.state("main.welcome", {
    url: "/welcome",
    templateUrl: 'templates/welcome-start.html',
    controller: 'WelcomeStartCtrl'
})
```

does not work.

Thanks in advance!
Henning

Answer (score 0):

You should consider "Modal View"

There is a predefined directive from ionic: $ionicModal

In simple words, it will just pop a view for you. This technique is used in login, info, add items and other simple one step procedures.

It is pretty easy, [Here is how to use it](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicModal/)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. `modal.show()` doesn't do anything, no error message and no modal. :-( And is it even possible to load different views into ionicModal? Because my welcome screen features a small tour with different `ion-view`s.

Comment: @Tilli85 Yes it supports different views. I implemented it and it works fine. just make sure that you do the example in the link I posted above. And when the modal is shown, use $state.go in you modal controller to navigate in the modal its self.